# How to shadow part of a list in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

I am making a PowerPoint presentation where I cover several topics. I have some slides where I recall the outline of my presentation with a list.
I would like to partially shadow the topics of my presentation that I am not going to talk about next, similarly to what is shown in here:

[image]

The image shown above is done with LaTeX, and as you can see it also shadows the list dot.

Can something similar be done in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this automatically in PowerPoint, but with some work. More exactly design your slide and after just make the text boxes and the bullet shapes gray and leave colored the one you need to present at that point. You can additionally add some animations.

Comment: Sigh, I feared this was the only way. I did as you suggested me, thank you